An Attempt at Creating Generic Min()/Max() for Fundamental Types
The simplest way one can achieve this is to have separate functions for each type with a suffix to differentiate between them like the following:
max_i();  // int
max_ui(); // unsigned int
// So on for other types.

But that becomes too cumbersome to remember. One could instead opt for function-like macros:
#define MAX(a, b)    ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define MIN(a, b)    ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

But these have the disadvantage that arguments are evaluated twice. This can cause some trouble in the following calls:
MAX(rand(), *p++)
MIN(--a, b++)

But a comment preceding the macros:
/* XXX: Do not pass in arguments with side-effects to these macros. */

takes the burden away from the implementer, and shifts it onto the developer (assuming they were different people).
But these macros are still frowned upon. One way in which the double evaluation part can be avoided is by using C23's auto and GNU C's compound expression statement (supported by Clang and GCC, I am unaware about others):
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    #define MAX(a, b) ({    \
        auto x = (a);       \
        auto y = (b);       \
        x > y ? x : y; })

    #define MIN(a, b) ({    \
        auto x = (a);       \
        auto y = (b);       \
        x < y ? x : y; })
#endif

These evaluate their arguments only once. But compound expression statement is not part of ISO C.
In which case we're only left with C11's _Generic:
#define MAX(a, b)    _Generic((a) + (b),                      \
                        signed char:                max_sc,   \
                        unsigned char:              max_uc,   \
                        char:                       max_c,    \
                        short int:                  max_si,   \
                        unsigned short int:         max_usi,  \
                        int:                        max_i,    \
                        unsigned int:               max_ui,   \
                        long int:                   max_li,   \
                        unsigned long int:          max_uli,  \
                        long long int:              max_lli,  \
                        unsigned long long int:     max_lli,  \
                        float:                      max_f,    \
                        double:                     max_d,    \
                        long double:                max_ld)(a, b)

#define MIN(a, b)    _Generic((a) + (b),                      \
                        signed char:                min_sc,   \
                        unsigned char:              min_uc,   \
                        char:                       min_c,    \
                        short int:                  min_si,   \
                        unsigned short int:         min_usi,  \
                        int:                        min_i,    \
                        unsigned int:               min_ui,   \
                        long int:                   min_li,   \
                        unsigned long int:          min_uli,  \
                        long long int:              min_lli,  \
                        unsigned long long int:     min_ulli, \
                        float:                      min_f,    \
                        double:                     min_d,    \
                        long double:                min_ld)(a, b)

/* Or provide only the declarations here and have a corresponding source file
   with all the definitions. */
#define gen_max(type, suffix) \
    [[gnu::always_inline, gnu::const]] static inline max_##suffix(type a, type b) \
    { return a > b ? a : b; } 

#define gen_min(type, suffix) \
    [[gnu::always_inline, gnu::const]] static inline min_##suffix(type a, type b) \
    { return a > b ? a : b; } 

gen_max(signed char, sc)
gen_max(unsigned char, uc)
gen_max(char, c)
gen_max(short int, si)
gen_max(unsigned short int, usi)
gen_max(int, i)
gen_max(unsigned int, ui)
gen_max(long int, li)
gen_max(unsigned long int, uli)
gen_max(long long int, lli)
gen_max(unsigned long long int, ulli)
gen_max(float, f)
gen_max(double, d)
gen_max(long double, ld)

gen_min(signed char, sc)
gen_min(unsigned char, uc)
gen_min(char, c)
gen_min(short int, si)
gen_min(unsigned short int, usi)
gen_min(int, i)
gen_min(unsigned int, ui)
gen_min(long int, li)
gen_min(unsigned long int, uli)
gen_min(long long int, lli)
gen_min(unsigned long long int, ulli)
gen_min(float, f)
gen_min(double, d)
gen_min(long double, ld)

This is both safe (doesn't evaluate the arguments twice), and Standard C code (unlike the second option).
Review Request:
In the third implementation, I have (a) + (b) as the controlling expression of _Generic, which would invoke undefined behaviour on signed integer overflow. How can I avoid that?
Would it be a good idea to merge these 3 implementations into a single source file, with this structure:
If __GNUC__ or __clang__ is defined, use the compound expression statement.
Else use C11's _Generic.

Unconditionally use MIN/MAX with a comment to warn against side-effects. 
And perhaps name the previous ones MIN_SAFE/MIN_MAX.

? Do you see any other problems with the code, or difference between the implementations that I am overlooking?

Follow-ups:

Generic Max Function for Integer Types (including Boolean)

Generic Min() for Integer Types (including Boolean)



typeof(a) could be used instead of auto too.

With _Generic((a) + (b), the type will never be narrower than int.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, the integer promotion rules. I don't see the use of keeping the 3 char types and signed short int and unsigned short int then.

Harith, aside from missing signed char, code is also missing _Bool from the primative type list, yet with 0*(a) + 0*(b), that can be ignored too.

I have char, signed char, and unsigned char in the code. (You suggested me to do so the last time I posted a question about _Generic here). Where do you find it absent?

I was recalling some other similar post and wrongly applied that here.

Let's go crazy and make N macros and N*N functions.
#define MAX_SC(a, b)    _Generic((b),     \
                        signed char:  max_scsc,   \
                        unsigned char:max_scuc,  \
                        // many others
                        long double: max_scld)((a), (b))

#define MAX_UC(a, b)    _Generic((b),     \
                        signed char:  max_ucsc,   \
                        unsigned char:max_ucuc,  \
                        // many others
                        long double: max_ucld)((a), (b))

// Many others MAX_..(a, b)

#define MAX(a, b)    _Generic((a),     \
                        signed char:  MAX_SC,   \
                        unsigned char:MAX_UC,  \
                        // many others
                        long double: MAX_LD)((a), (b))

Now the max of INT_MIN, UINT_MAX will be UINT_MAX
and the min of INT_MIN, UINT_MAX will be INT_MIN.
unsigned max_uii_(unsigned a, int b) {
  return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
}

int min_uii_(unsigned a, int b) {
  return (a > INT_MAX) ? b : ((int) a < b ? (int) a : b);
}


Mixed FP and integer types remain a problem.


Perhaps don't support FP because fmax()/fmin() exist?

@Harith Its a type issue: example : the minimum of -0x37777777, nextafterf(-powf(2,31),0)?  is INT_MIN+1, but that is not exactly representable as a float. Note" fmax()/fmin() exist since C99.

14 macros and 196 functions for MAX(), 14 macros and 196 macros for MIN(). Nay, I'd fall back to the lovely one-liners.

@Harith Mixed types narrower that int can use max_i_i_().  For mixed types like int, unsigned, the _Generic() could not resolve and lead to compiler failure.  This failure may be preferable than MAX(-1, UINTMAX - 1u) resulting in UINTMAX.  With this approach only about 8 MAX_() and 8 functions macros needed.

https://godbolt.org/z/9feevhavM <== Is this what you had in mind?

@Harith We could use _Generic((b) + 0) to eliminate the need for char, signed char, unsigned char, signed short, unsigned short cases.

There's a bug in MAX(). MAX_UC() et cetera would not be expanded without ().

The compound expression statement would restrict the scope of x and y, but there may still be conflicts with variable names that occur within the expressions that are substituted for a and b. For instance, if MAX() is called like this:
MAX(x++, y + 1);

The first statement of the compound statement expression would become:
auto x = (x++);

and the second statement would become:
auto y = (y + 1);

GCC's documentation suggests prefixing the identifiers with underscores to avoid these conflicts. Though I wouldn't second that, since identifiers prefixed with underscores are reserved.
You could use a temp/tmp suffix or prefix, or something similar.

Edit: I have found a better mechanism for generating a unique name:
We are going to use the C Preprocessor to help us, and cdecl 3.0, which supports nearly all C and C++ Standards and extensions, to expand the macros:
$ cdecl
cdecl> #define CONCAT2_EXPAND(a, b)    a ## b
cdecl> #define CONCAT2(a, b)           CONCAT2_EXPAND(a, b)
cdecl> #define UNIQUE_NAME(prefix)     CONCAT2(CONCAT2(prefix, _), __LINE__)
cdecl> expand UNIQUE_NAME(var)
UNIQUE_NAME(var) => CONCAT2(CONCAT2(prefix, _), __LINE__)
| prefix => var
UNIQUE_NAME(var) => CONCAT2(CONCAT2(var, _), __LINE__)
| CONCAT2(CONCAT2(var, _), __LINE__) => CONCAT2_EXPAND(a, b)
| | a => CONCAT2(var, _)
| | | CONCAT2(var, _) => CONCAT2_EXPAND(a, b)
| | | | a => var
| | | | b => _
| | | CONCAT2(var, _) => CONCAT2_EXPAND(var, _)
| | | | CONCAT2_EXPAND(var, _) => a ## b
| | | | CONCAT2_EXPAND(var, _) => var ## _
| | | | CONCAT2_EXPAND(var, _) => var_
| | | CONCAT2(var, _) => var_
| | a => var_
| | b => __LINE__
| | | __LINE__ => 42
| | b => 42
| CONCAT2(var_, 42) => CONCAT2_EXPAND(var_, 42)
| | CONCAT2_EXPAND(var_, 42) => a ## b
| | CONCAT2_EXPAND(var_, 42) => var_ ## 42
| | CONCAT2_EXPAND(var_, 42) => var_42
| CONCAT2(var_, 42) => var_42
UNIQUE_NAME(var) => var_42
cdecl> 

CONCAT2() simply concatenates its arguments. CONCAT2_EXPAND() is required because the ## operator does not expand its operands. UNIQUE_NAME() concatenates the prefix passed to it with the current line number.
The expand command above shows the complete working (the actual output is very colorful. Unfortunately, I can not replicate it here). This is likely to generate quite a unique identifier.
I found this at Handy C/C++ Preprocessor Macros. This blog is written by the same person who wrote v3 of cdecl. cdecl's codebase makes much use of these macros as well. See the blog for more preprocessor tricks.
None of these function-like macros take care of mixed types:
If MAX() is passed a signed type and an unsigned type, the signed type is likely going to be very converted to a very large unsigned type. The current 3 versions of MAX() would only work properly for types with same signs.
For long and int, good.
For unsigned and unsigned long, good.
For int and unsigned, not good.
For int and unsigned long, not good.
Overflow is not a problem:
As @Jonathan Leffer states in the comments of this StackOverflow question: Understanding C11's _Generic:

Note that §6.5.1.1 Generic selection ¶3 says: The controlling expression of a generic selection is not evaluated.. Since it isn't evaluated, it can't overflow. It makes sense. The controlling expression determines the type at compile time; overflow happens at run-time.

So (a) + (b) is correct, except that as @chux mentions in the comments:

With _Generic((a) + (b), the type will never be narrower than int.


This solution would not work with MSVC:
According to the C Standard, 6.2.5.15, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n869/n869.pdf.gz

The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively
called the character types. The implementation shall define char to
have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char. 32)
CHAR_MIN, defined in <limits.h>, will have one of the values 0 or
SCHAR_MIN, and this can be used to distinguish the two options.
Irrespective of the choice made, char is a separate type from the
other two and is not compatible with either.

But not surprisingly, MSVC defines char and signed char as identical types, which means that in a _Generic expression, both char and signed char shall be compatible. I believe a diagnostic is required in such a case. See: _Generic char, signed char, unsigned char are not distinct in C11. It had been reported to Microsoft almost 4 years ago, and has not yet been fixed, and probably would not be.
To circumvent this problem, the simplest solution would be to use the original + 0 trick to implicitly promote to an int, and not check any char types.

To avoid conflict in macros, I tend to suffix them with an underscore and a randomly chosen alphanumeric suffix. Verbose, but when life deals you lemons...

My apologies if the edit sounds more like a promotion, I have just become very fond of the program. :)

You're caught between a rock and a hard place here. Using __LINE__ is a bad idea, because there's nothing preventing me from calling UNIQUE_NAME twice on the same line, and then it's not really unique any longer, is it? __COUNTER__ would give a unique name, but it'd be too unique: if UNIQUE_NAME was used in an inline function, included in two different translation units, then the expanded code of the inline function would differ between the two TUs (unless they have the same includes), which is Undefined Behavior.

@MatthieuM. Well, all uses for a given PREFIX that refer to the same name must be on the same line, so calling UNIQUE_NAME twice on the same line with the same PREFIX is a valid use case if one wishes to refer to the same name. If the intent was to get a second unique identifier, the documentation of UNIQUE_NAME() can specify that PREFIX must be different in such a case. 2) The point about inline functions is not something I had in mind. Thank you. I have mostly found UNIQUE_NAME() useful in macros since I discovered it.

That's only if the prefix is user-facing, though. If UNIQUE_NAME is used within a macro and that macro doesn't expose prefix (but picks one), then using the macro twice on the same line (possibly nested, as in MAX(a, MAX(b, c))) will cause different variables to end with the same unique name.

@MatthieuM. You're very far-sighted. Do any other problems come to mind? (I would add them to UNIQUE_NAME's documentation.)

I'm less far-sighted and more... experienced :'( I can't think of anything else, I mostly used C++ so I was able to mostly stay away from macros in general, just "had" to use them to implement proper logging and introspection.

@MatthieuM. I looked around and asked a question on SO and found out that C, unlike C++, doesn't require inline definitions of a function to be identical. So the first problem entailing UB is not a problem in C.

Well, that's interesting. I hadn't realized this was a point of divergence between C and C++. There is still the risk of C code being included in a C++ project, so for small functions I'd recommend static inline, but for a pure C project, it sure makes things easier.

UB
(a) + (b)


which would invoke undefined behaviour on signed integer overflow.

Well sure, integer addition can overflow.
But we have operations that don't, right?
Like all of the bitwise operations.
XOR seems a fair candidate.

You were right that {} would ensure that the local variables are only visible in that scope. But there's another problem. There may still be conflicts with variable names that occur within the expressions that are substituted for a and b.  For instance, if I call MAX() like this: MAX(x++, y + 1), the first statement would become: auto x = (x++);, and the second statement would become: auto y = (y + 1);. GCC's documentation suggests prefixing the identifiers with underscores to avoid these conflicts.

Yup, it's a generic issue with macro expansion. The scheme / lisp community refers to it as hygienic macros, and has a few ways of addressing it. These include special parser syntax, and (gensym), which generates a brand new guaranteed unique symbol for use in the expansion.

Bitwise operations don't work for floats.

Instead of (a) + (b), perhaps 0*(a) + 0*(b) to get the common type and avoid overflow?

Multiply by zero is brilliant, yes, do that.

Bug With Floating-Point NaN
The a > b ? a : b check will fail when b is NaN and a is not, since comparison with NaN is always false.  The expected behavior is to return a.  Use fmaximum_num, fmaximum_numf or fmaximum_numl for these types. (Unlike the fmax family, these are defined to handle NaN and comparisons between +0 and -0 correctly.)
Prior to C23, there is theoretically another issue that could come up with the sign-and-magnitude representation of -0.  In C23, all signed integral types are two’s-complement.

"since comparison with NaN is always false." --> that is an IEEE spec that C is not obliged to follow - although that result is common.  "The a > b ? a : b check will fail when b is NaN and a is not," could fail or pass in C.

"The expected behavior is to return a" --> C2X discusses that in fmax() when b is a quiet NAN and appears silent when both a,b are quiet, yet different NANs.  It is also quiet on fmax(+0.0,-0,0) and  fmax(-0.0,+0,0) - one of those get returned?  I do not see C specifying which.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Looking it up, in C23, there is a separate fmaximum_num family of functions that does specify that +0.0 > -0.0 and any comparison between a number and NaN returns the number.
